# Rails unwanted duplication with the nested_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm not sure what is happening here. I've checked everything here but I'm getting this double file upload field:

[image]

[image]

Even if I use only one field it still renders two images.

`_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= nested_form_for @home, :html=>{:multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @home.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@home.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this blog from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @home.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |attachment_form|  %>
      <%= attachment_form.file_field :file %>
      <br /><br />
      <%= attachment_form.link_to_remove "Remove this attachment" %>
      <% for attachment in @home.attachments %>
        <div class="show_image">
          <%= image_tag attachment.file_url(:thumb).to_s %>
        </div>
      <% end %>      
    <% end %>
    <br /><br />
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add attachmnt", :attachments %>
  </p>
  <br /><br />
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
  <br /><br />
<% end %>
```

Models:
`attachment.rb`:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :file
   belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
   mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

`home.rb`:

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :attachments_attributes
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

`homes_controller.rb`:

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /homes
  # GET /homes.json
  def index
    @homes = Home.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @homes }
    end
  end

  # GET /homes/1
  # GET /homes/1.json
  def show
    @home = Home.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @home }
    end
  end

  # GET /homes/new
  # GET /homes/new.json
  def new
    @home = Home.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @home }
    end
  end

  # GET /homes/1/edit
  def edit
    @home = Home.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /homes
  # POST /homes.json
  def create
    @home = Home.new(params[:home])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @home.save
        format.html { redirect_to @home, :notice => 'Home was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @home, :status => :created, :location => @home }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @home.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /homes/1
  # PUT /homes/1.json
  def update
    @home = Home.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @home.update_attributes(params[:home])
        format.html { redirect_to @home, :notice => 'Home was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @home.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /homes/1
  # DELETE /homes/1.json
  def destroy
    @home = Home.find(params[:id])
    @home.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to homes_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

How do I stop this from happening?

Any help with this would be great, I've been looking at this for hours!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be bad data created while getting this set up. Maybe there are previous attachments on the `Home` object that are not being displayed correctly, but still exist in the database. Does the same problem happen if you create a new `Home` and attempt to add attachments?

The `fields_for` block is creating a button and a display of each photo for each `attachment` it's being passed. I think that's why you're seeing the duplication. The `fields_for` is an iterator on `attachments` with a duplicate iterator inside it (`for attachment in @home.attachments`).